# How to treat underscore as part of the word?

Tags: evil, syntax, syntax-table

I use Emacs + `evil` mode.

When I position the cursor on `e` (in normal state) in a chunk of text such as `abc_def_ghi`, `ciw` (change inner word) changes only the `def` part of the string, while Vim would change the entire `abc_def_ghi`.

How can I force `evil` to treat the underscore as Vim does (ie, as part of the word)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The simplest workaround: use `cio` (see [here](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#underscore-is-not-a-word-character)), or use `ciW` to select a whitespace-delimited word.

The bigger issue has to do with the value of the `_` character in the [syntax table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html).  The issue is that `_` is, by default, a symbol constituent in the syntax table, and you want to treat it as a word constituent.

If you're using emacs 24.4, you could try enabling [`superword-mode`](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/08/27/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-superword-mode/).  I haven't tried it myself, so your mileage may vary.

An alternative is simply to modify the syntax table yourself and tell Emacs you want it to treat the `_` character as a word constituent, like so:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

After you do that, `ciw` works as you want it to, such that it will select all of `abc_def_ghi` rather than just `def`.

Doing it this way, however, may be overkill, especially if you only want the `_` to count as part of the word for the text object.  Instead, you can advise `evil-inner-word` as follows:

```lisp
(defadvice evil-inner-word (around underscore-as-word activate)
  (let ((table (copy-syntax-table (syntax-table))))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" table)
    (with-syntax-table table
      ad-do-it)))
```

Now, `_` is still a symbol constituent for everything *except* for the inner-word text object, so `ciw` will do precisely what you want without touching the functionality of anything else.

You can read more about modifying syntax tables on the [EmacsWiki node](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable).

Comment: This works like a charm. To alter all the movements (`w`, `aw`, etc.), you can do the same with the following functions too: `evil-forward-word-begin`,`evil-forward-word-end`,`evil-backward-word-begin`,`evil-backward-word-end`,`evil-a-word`,`evil-inner-word`. Note: you need to  change `underscore-as-word` into different, unique (arbitrary) values.

Comment: `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")` didn't work for me for some reason. Doing it interactively didn't work either. Any idea why or how I can debug this? I'm on Spacemacs in case that's relevant.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1261#issuecomment-150334654) explains my problem. Apparently you have to refer to the target syntax table explictly. In my case I used `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" rust-mode-syntax-table)`, then it worked.

Comment: What are the unintended effects of modifying the syntax entry?

Comment: FTR: `superword-mode` doesn't affect movement in `evil-mode`. So it's not a constituent to modifying syntax tables.

Answer (score 48):

The following snippet will make Evil treat an Emacs *symbol* as a word.

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'evil
    (defalias #'forward-evil-word #'forward-evil-symbol)
    ;; make evil-search-word look for symbol rather than word boundaries
    (setq-default evil-symbol-word-search t))
```

This has the advantage that it changes depending on the language:

```
foo-bar
```

is one symbol in `lisp-mode` but two symbols (separated by `-`) in `c-mode`.

Answer (score 17):

The [spacemacs FAQ](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/doc/FAQ.org#include-underscores-in-word-motions) offers the following language-specific solution:

```
;; For python
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
;; For ruby
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook #'(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
;; For Javascript
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
```

It also works in regular emacs. With evil on, it works with all word-related commands (`w`, `e`, `*`, `#`, etc)

More generally, this will do it for all major modes:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
```

Comment: Is using `'prog-mode-hook` an option to cover every language?

Answer (score 5):

The [`evil` FAQ](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#underscore-is-not-a-word-character) says if you want the underscore to be recognised as a word character:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

Alternatively, you can change the `w` shortcut to move by *symbols* instead of by *words*:

```lisp
(defalias 'forward-evil-word 'forward-evil-symbol)
```

Answer (score 3):

Emacs 24 introduced `superword-mode`, a minor mode that treats underscores as part of words. `evil-mode` respects this setting.

Here is the documentation:

> `(superword-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle superword movement and editing (Superword mode).
>   With a prefix argument `ARG`, enable Superword mode if `ARG` is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
>   the mode if `ARG` is omitted or nil.
>
> Superword mode is a buffer-local minor mode.  Enabling it changes
>   the definition of words such that symbols characters are treated
>   as parts of words: e.g., in `superword-mode`,
>   `"this_is_a_symbol"` counts as one word.

Comment: If you are using `evil-mode`, unfortunately, there is a bug when `superword-mode` is enable. It causes some erratic behavior when `evil-forward-word-begin` is called: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/721

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't quite answer the OP's question but thought I'd put this here for completeness.
I also like evil's default behavior (esp. for python and lisp-dialects where I might only want to change part of a name) UNLESS I'm searching for a word under the cursor, i.e. with "*" or "#", in which case I'd like to search for the *symbol* under the cursor.
You can easily modify `evil` to adhere to this by setting `evil-symbol-word-search`, i.e.:

```
(setq evil-symbol-word-search t)
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. In addition to this setting, I also like to have `W` (capital rather than lowercase) refer to symbols rather than `WORD`s, for which you can use this: `(defalias #'forward-evil-WORD #'forward-evil-symbol)`. With these two settings, your # and * search for symbols, `w` moves by word stopping at underscores, hyphens and spaces, while `W` moves by symbol, stopping at meaningful points for the code.

Comment: But this makes `/foo/bar` to also be a word in many modes 

Answer (score 1):

Not being satisfied with side-effects of `evil-symbol-word-search` or having to hardcode `(modify-syntax-entry)` for every mode, I found that apparently minor mode hooks are run after major mode syntax table is created. So you can add a hook to modify syntax table to `evil-mode` hook and it should just work.

```lisp
(defun myhook-evil-mode ()
  ;; I want underscore be part of word syntax table, but not in regexp-replace buffer
  ;; where I'm more comfortable having more verbose navigation with underscore not
  ;; being a part of a word. To achieve this I check if current mode has a syntax
  ;; table different from the global one. The `(eq)' is a lightweight test of whether
  ;; the args point to the same object.
  (unless (eq (standard-syntax-table) (syntax-table))
    ;; make underscore part of a word
    (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
(add-hook 'evil-local-mode-hook 'myhook-evil-mode)
```

Maybe not optimal as it's executed every time a new buffer is created, but shouldn't matter in this case. What does though is that this allowed me [to get rid of a humongous 49 lines paragraph](https://github.com/Hi-Angel/dotfiles/commit/4620b4d11afcef2fc22133c9573d0eb712f7bcc9#diff-ae51cdd59e3f8b0b021370d52c4d2651c0f0d5cf2ef163b8c81879251c26c277L298-L346) that was modifying syntax table of every possible mode I got to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I actually quite like this behavior since I might want to just edit a part of the word and keep the other parts intact. If I want to go over the whole word I can always use `E`, `W` or `B`, the uppercase variants. This gives me more fine-grained control.