# How do I search the whole word in swoop?

Tags: helm, search

I wish to search a separate word with helm-swoop. There should be some trick for this I guess. For instance I know that to search 2 words will be like word1\|word2 and to search the end of the line like: endofline$

So does anybody know how to search a whole word only? Thanks.

Comment: Good question, I didn't realize you could do this until you asked!

Comment: Note that `$` matches the end of a **line**, not the end of a **word**

Comment: True, I'll correct that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any regexps supported by Emacs, which provides `\b` as a match for the boundary of a word. So swooping for `\bin\b` will match `in` but not `input`, `begin` or `being`.

The full list of Emacs-supported regexps is in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) ([second page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)).

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it works.

Comment: Yes, it works, also if you know how to force it consider this sign '\_' as part of the word please let me know. It doesn't consider signs '(', ')' as part of the word what is good, but for C coding emacs should consider '\_' as part of the word. Thanks.

Comment: The regexps use the syntax table for the current mode. By default, in c-mode `_` is treated as a symbol. You can change that with `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")` in your c-mode hook. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable or http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9583/how-to-treat-underscore-as-part-of-the-word/9584#9584

Comment: This does not work for me. Ubuntu 16.04 Emacs 25.3.2. It seems the "\b" doesn't work at all.

Comment: @CodyChan \b should work, so if it doesn't for you we're missing some key information. Perhaps you could open a new question and provide a detailed explanation of what you've tried. Otherwise we don't know enough to help you.

Comment: @Tyler \b doesn't work for me, but `\_<word\_>` works.

Comment: @CodyChan `\b` works for words, `\_<` works for symbols, so that's a hint about details you're not providing. Please open a new question if you want more help