# `eval-after-load` gets executed, but syntax-table is missing

Tags: syntax-table, eval-after-load

In the course of using Emacs I got a dozen of lines that [simply make underscore part of a word](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9583/2671#how-to-treat-underscore-as-part-of-the-word), and most of them upon byte-compilation are causing warnings like `reference to free variable ‘php-mode-syntax-table’`.

I asked on IRC how to deal with that, and it seems the most optimal way is to use `eval-after-load` to modify the syntax table. So I made up the code below:

```
(eval-after-load 'text-mode
  '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" text-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'rust-mode
  '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" rust-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
  '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" c++-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
  '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" c-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'python
  '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" python-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?- "w" lisp-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'gud
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" gud-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'php-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" php-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" haskell-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'shell-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'markdown-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" markdown-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
(eval-after-load 'diff-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" diff-mode-syntax-table)) ;; make underscore part of a word
```

For some reason, Emacs fails at runtime with error like

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/constantine/.emacs’:

Symbol's value as variable is void: php-mode-syntax-table
```

This error not only happens for `php-mode`, but also for `gud-mode`, `haskell-mode`. I can't understand what's causing it — if Emacs really loaded the file, it would clearly have the syntax table. What should I do?

Comment: To future readers: I ended up reducing the above bunch of code into the following, hope this helps `(dolist (mode '(text-mode rust-mode cc-mode python lisp-mode gud php-mode haskell-mode shell-mode markdown-mode diff-mode))
  (eval-after-load mode
    '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))`

Comment: Nvm the above comment, although I leave it in case somebody else attempts the like: the `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")` modifies syntax table of major mode of current buffer, but it not necessarily matches the mode being loaded aka one of those in the `dolist` list. I don't think the code in question can be further reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes `'` on many of your examples. i.e.,

```
(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode
  (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" haskell-mode-syntax-table))
```

That means the unquoted bit, i.e., `(modify-syntax-entry ...)` is getting evaluated immediately, it isn't deferred until after `haskell-mode` is loaded. You can correct this by adding all the missing `'` characters. eg:

```
(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode
  '(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" haskell-mode-syntax-table))
```