# How to 'modify-syntax-entry' for a major mode?

Tags: syntax-table, syntax

Following [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9583), when I type `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")`
and do `M-x eval-region`, it has the effect I'm looking for, albeit only for that buffer. I've put `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")` in my `.emacs` file, however and after restarting, it's *not* having effect in my C/C++ code.

I'm using Emacs `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.13) of 2019-12-11`.  My OS is: `Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)`.

*<sub>There are questions with nearly the exact same title, but their accepted answers do not work for C/C++ mode, so this is a different question.</sub>*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each major mode has its own syntax and syntax table. If you just put `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")` in your init file, it gets evaluated in the buffer that is current when your init file is loaded -- not in a C/C++ buffer.

To evaluate that sexp when in a C/C++ buffer you can put it in a function, which you add to the mode hook.  For example (untested):

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
```

But it's generally better to use a named, not an anonymous, hook function. For example:

```lisp
(defun foo () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w"))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'foo)
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than modifying the syntax tables, you can instead use the built-in `superword-mode`:

> Superword mode is a buffer-local minor mode.  Enabling it changes
> the definition of words such that symbols characters are treated
> as parts of words: e.g., in ‘superword-mode’,
> "this_is_a_symbol" counts as one word.

You can enable it per mode using a a hook: `(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'superword-mode)` or globally with `(global-superword-mode 1)` in your `.emacs`

Comment: This helped a lot! It fixed a problem where mu4e was hanging on message replies: https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1779

Comment: I get `Wrong type argument: symbolp, ((lambda nil (set (make-local-variable (quote whitespace-line-column)) 127)))` unless I put a single quote before c++-mode-hook: `(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'superword-mode)`