# How to replace the highlighted word in yasnippet?

Tags: spacemacs, yasnippet

After the snippet gets expanded the cursor is put to the first section (long_name).

What key do I need to press in order to **replace long_name**?

Evil operations like e.g. `cw` or `ce` change *long* or to the line end, while I only want to replace **long_name**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to treat the underscore as part of the word, as Vim does.  The best answer is probably [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9584/418) - look at the solution adding advice around `evil-inner-word`

Comment: Indeed. The second answer does what I need (replace word with ce): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20717/21118